# Share Steam games bought on parent account and computer to child account and computer

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

We have a number of games that have been bought with my Steam account and installed on my laptop. My child is now to get his own computer.

Preferrably he would have his own Steam account. If we want to install the games on his computer, is it possible to link accounts so they will be visible to him?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable family sharing through 'Setting' -> 'Family' and check 'Authorize Library Sharing on this computer'. After that you can click on 'Manage other computers' to add computers.

Note that if you play a game on a shared library, that nobody else can play a game from that entire library. So, if you are playing a game, your child has to wait untill you close the game.

Also note that "Not all games support Family Library Sharing".

For more info that a look at the [support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3784-QLBM-5731) of steam.

Comment: This is partially imprecise: if you were to play your own games in offline mode your shared library would still be avayable for use to an user that has been enabled to share the library. This is a workaround and might possibly be patched in the future although i doubt it will be.

Comment: @Wolfaloo that is a pretty clever work around :). Did you actually test this? Maybe it isn't possible to game in offline mode if you shared your library.

Comment: I did test this, i am unsure if this breaks any TOS since valve specifies only one account is allowed to use the library at a time. Being offline of course prevents you from playing online and even if you have a dedicated server for a multiplayer game, most games check your game key/player id to prevent this (all valve games for example), most coop games like borderlands, dying light, dead Island ecc.. will allow you to offline LAN coop owning only 1 copy of said game, i doubt this is fixable since being offline means u won't communicate valve's servers